# add prefix to each column with sed

Tags: sed

I have a header and what to add the prefix "f4_" to each column.

I tried this:

```
echo -e  p.value"\t"beta | sed "s/\</f4_/g"
```

and got this:

```
f4_p.f4_value   f4_beta
```

I want this:

```
f4_p.value   f4_beta
```

I think the special character . in the header is messing this up but I am not sure how to fix

Comment: Do you have to do it with `sed`? It will be easier with `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```bash
printf 'p.value\tbeta\n' |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) ($i != "") && $i = "f4_" $i} 1'

f4_p.value  f4_beta
```

For a **no loop** solution suggest you to use this `gnu-awk` solutiom:

```bash
printf 'p.value\tbeta\n' |
awk -v RS='[\t\n]+' 'NF{$0 = "f4_" $0} {ORS=RT} 1'

f4_p.value  f4_beta
```

Comment: That's exactly what they tried, and you're getting the same incorrect result. He doesn't want to match the word boundary after `p.`

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that. Changed sed to awk now

Comment: You have to check if the column is not empty.. For example `'p.value\t\tbeta\t\n'`

Comment: @ufopilot: Good point, it is fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You can add the prefix at the start or after TAB only with

```
echo -e  p.value"\t"beta | sed -E "s/^|\t/&f4_/g"
# => f4_p.value f4_beta
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/S3PXuX).

Here,

- `-E` enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `^|\t` - matches either start of a string or a TAB
- `&` in the replacement puts back what was matched.

Comment: `printf '\tp.value\tbeta\t\n' |sed -E "s/^|\t/&f4_/g"` —>  
`^ f4_p.value f4_beta f4_ $`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Yes, as expected as per OP. Adding at the start and after a TAB, as in my explanation.

Comment: i'm saying if input happens to have trailing tab(s), it would append into blank space

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Again, this is as expected, every field in OP must be preceded with a prefix. Nowhere is it stated the field must not be empty. See "add the prefix "f4_" to ***each column***". `sed -E "s/(^|\t)([^[:space:]])/\1f4_\2/g"` [would cater](https://ideone.com/7Psodt) for the scenarios with empty fields.

Comment: up to u, if u think such a literal parsing of OP's inquiry is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add it to each column, you should add it after each column separator. In this case, the separator is `\t`:

```
$ echo -e  p.value"\t"beta | sed "s/\t/&f4_/g"
p.value f4_beta
```

(Here `&` means "the part `s///` matched before," which will be `\t`)

This will miss, of course, the first column, so we add the beginning of line wildcard (`^`) to the matching regex. For that, we use the `\|` operator, which allows both of its sides to be matched:

```
$ echo -e  p.value"\t"beta | sed "s/^\|\t/&f4_/g"
f4_p.value  f4_beta
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
echo -e  p.value"\t"beta | perl -F'\t' -ane 'print join "\t", map { "f4_$_" } @F;'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score -1):

no need to loop the fields at all :

> ```
>  printf 'p.value\tbeta\n' | 
>
>  {m,g}awk 'gsub("[^\11]+",(__)"&")^_' FS='[\411]' __='f4_'
> ```

```
f4_p.value  f4_beta
```